# How to add grouping mechanism inside for loop in bash

Tags: bash

I have a for loop that loops through a list of files, and inside the for loop a script is called, that takes this file name as input.
Something like

```
for file in $(cat list_of_files) ; do
    script $file
done
```

the file `list_of_files` has files like

```
file1
file2
file3
...
```

so with each iteration, one file is processed.

I have to design something like, loop through all the files, group them into groups of 3 , so that in one loop, script will be called 3 times, and not one by one,and then again the other 3 will be called in second loop iteration and so on

something like,

```
for file in $(cat list_of_files) ; do
     # do somekind of grouping here
     call one more loop to run the sript.sh 3 times, so something like
     for i=1 to 3 and then next iteration from 4 to 6 and so on..
     script.sh $file1
     script.sh $file2
     script.sh $file3
done
```

I am struggling currently on how to get this looping done and i am stuck here and could not think of efficient way here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Change `for ... in` to `while read`

> ```
> for file in $(cat list_of_files)
> ```

This style of loop is subtly dangerous and/or incorrect. It won't work right on file names with spaces, asterisks, or other special characters. As a general rule, avoid `for x in $(...)` loops. For more details, see:

- [Bash Pitfalls: `for f in $(ls *.mp3)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

A safer alternative is to use `while read` along with [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), like so:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    ...
done < <(cat list_of_files)
```

It's ugly, I'll admit, but it will handle special characters safely. It split apart file names with spaces and it won't expand `*` globs. For more details on what this is doing, see:

- [Unix.SE: Understanding “IFS= read -r line”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line).

You can then remove the [Useless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) and use a simple redirection instead:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    ...
done < list_of_files
```

#### Read 3 at a time

So far these changes haven't answered your core question, how to group files 3 at a time. The switch to `read` has actually served a second purpose. It makes grouping easy. The trick is to call `read` multiple times per iteration. This is an easy change with `while read`; it's not so easy with `for ... in`.

Here's what that looks like:

```
while IFS= read -r file1 &&
      IFS= read -r file2 &&
      IFS= read -r file3
do
    script.sh "$file1"
    script.sh "$file2"
    script.sh "$file3"
done < list_of_files
```

This calls `read` three times, and once all three succeed it proceeds to the loop body.

It will work great if you always have a multiple of 3 items to process. If not, it will mess up at the end and skip the last file or two. If that's an issue we can update it to try to handle that case.

```
while IFS= read -r file1; do
    IFS= read -r file2
    IFS= read -r file3

    script.sh "$file1"
    [[ -n $file2 ]] && script.sh "$file2"
    [[ -n $file3 ]] && script.sh "$file3"
done < list_of_files
```

#### Run the scripts in parallel

If I understand your question right, you also want to run the scripts at the same time rather than sequentially, one after the other. If so, the way to do that is to append `&`, which will cause them to run in the background. Then call `wait` to block until they have all finished before proceeding.

```
while IFS= read -r file1; do
    IFS= read -r file2
    IFS= read -r file3

    script.sh "$file1" &
    [[ -n $file2 ]] && script.sh "$file2" &
    [[ -n $file3 ]] && script.sh "$file3" &
    wait
done < list_of_files
```

Comment: @prex : You should write the important pieces (i.e. _process the files 3 by 3 in parallel_) into the question, not into a comment!

Comment: @John Kugelman Thank you, this way works. one small thing, how can i start the 4th run when the 1st run is done here, and the 5th one once the 2nd is done and so on, while still running 3 processes in parallel.

Comment: I am trying to modify this code ,but currently the script is exiting after the 3rd process because of & . can you please help

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
xargs -d $'\n' -L 1 -P 3 script.sh <list_of_files
```

`-P 3` runs 3 processes in parallel. Each of those gets the input of one line (due to `-L 1`), and the `-d` options ensures that spaces in an input line are not considered separate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash arrays to store the filenames until you get 3 of them:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=()

while IFS= read -r f; do
    files+=( "$f" )
    (( ${#files[@]} < 3 )) && continue
    script.sh "${files[0]}"
    script.sh "${files[1]}"
    script.sh "${files[2]}"
    files=()
done < list_of_files
```

However, I think that John Kugelman's answer is simpler, then better: it uses less bash-specific features, then it can be more easily converted to a POSIX version.

Comment: The effect is different too: JohnKugelman's answer processes all fils. With your solution, if (for instance) the total number of files is 2, you don't invoke `script.sh` at all.

Comment: @user1934428 Indeed. The exact behaviour about this case is not given in the Q

Comment: @user1934428 It can be corrected by calling the script for the remaining array elements after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you should not mix script languages if you don't absolutely have to

you can start with that

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

PATH_FILES = "/yourfolder"

def yourFunction(file_name):
    file_path = PATH_FILES + "/" + file_name
    print(file_path) #or do something else
    print(file_path) #or do something else
    print(file_path) #or do something else


file_names = [f for f in listdir(PATH_FILES) if isfile(join(PATH_FILES, f))]
for file_name in file_names:
     yourFunction(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `mapfile` aka `readarray` is available/acceptable. (bash4+ is required)

Assuming `script.sh` can accept multiple input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while mapfile -tn3 files && (( ${#files[*]} == 3 )); do
  script.sh "${files[@]}"
done < list_of_files
```

---

otherwise loop through the array named `files`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while mapfile -tn3 files && (( ${#files[*]} == 3 )); do
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    script.sh "$file"
  done
done < list_of_files
```

---

The body after the `do` will run/execute if there are always 3 lines if there is not enough lines to satisfy 3 lines until the end of the file, just remove the

```
&& (( ${#files[*]} == 3 ))
```

from the script.

---

or do it manually one-by-one, but it should have 3 lines to be processed (the file) until the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while mapfile -tn3 files && (( ${#files[*]} == 3 )); do
  script.sh "${file[0]}"
  script.sh "${file[1]}"
  script.sh "${file[2]}"
done < list_of_files
```